# Resizing background image of a div using css

Tags: html, css

I have a background image in the following div.

```
#logo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    min-height: 75px;
    min-width: 75px;
    background: url(rotarywheel.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
}
```

I want to resize this logo div based on the window size (mobile,tablet, etc.) How is it possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

> The background-size CSS property specifies the size of the background images. The size of the image can be fully constrained or only partially in order to preserve its intrinsic ratio.

Comment: but it is not resizing based on window size

Comment: Set the width and height of `#logo` to a percent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make anything depend on the window-size, you probably want to look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). This is modified from the example at the top of that page:

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #logo {
        width: 500px;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url('500-200-bg.png') no-repeat;
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **background-size** CSS property

eg

```
background-size:100px 50px;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use background-size in percentage, and width also. as you have same ratio of width and height of div.

```
#logo {
margin-top: 15px;
min-height:75px;
min-width: 75px; /*value in percentage or em;*/
background: url(rotarywheel.png) no-repeat;
background-size:25%;  /*value in percentage or em;*/
float: left;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

use the css id tags so that when you call make a tag with that id it will present differently.

Comment: The ID is already used for `#logo` - you'll need more than that to change the size of the background or the div.